# Array remains empty after elements were pushed in a method

Tags: arrays, ruby, class

```
class Player
  def initialize(hp, attack, defence, gold)
    @hp = hp
    @attack = attack
    @defence = defence
    @gold = gold
    @inventory = inventory
  end

  def inventory
    @inventory = []
  end

  def buy(item)
    if @gold >= item.price
      @gold-=item.price
      puts "You hand over #{item.price} gold, and get the #{item.name}."
      puts "You have #{gold} gold left over."
      @inventory.push([item.name,item.price,item.attack,item.defence])
      puts "ITEMS IN INV: #{@inventory}" # output: ITEMS IN INV: [["Dagger", 4, 1, 0], ["Mucky Tunic", 2, 0, 2]]
    else
      puts "You can't afford this item."
    end
  end
end

 player = Player.new(10,1,2,6)
 puts player.inventory.inspect # output: []
```

The `inventory.push` line pushes the element to the array while it is inside the method, but when returned outside the method, the `inventory` array is empty. This is confusing because other variables that were changed inside that method in the same way come back as altered.

sample output when printed from inside the buy method:

```
ITEMS IN INV: [["Dagger", 4, 1, 0], ["Mucky Tunic", 2, 0, 2]]
```

output with `player.inventory.inspect` outside of the method:

```
[]
```

Comment: BTW, instead of `puts player.inventory.inspect` you can write `p player.inventory`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you call your `inventory` method:

```
def inventory
  @inventory = []
end
```

... it assigns a new (empty) array to `@inventory`, thus overwriting any existing items.

The correct way is to either assign `@inventory` in `initialize` and just return it from within the getter:

```
class Player
  def initialize(hp, attack, defence, gold)
    @hp = hp
    @attack = attack
    @defence = defence
    @gold = gold 
    @inventory = []   
  end

  def inventory
    @inventory
  end

  # ...
end
```

or to not assign it at all in `initialize` and use the [conditional assignment](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment) operator:

```
class Player
  def initialize(hp, attack, defence, gold)
    @hp = hp
    @attack = attack
    @defence = defence
    @gold = gold    
  end

  def inventory
    @inventory ||= []
  end

  # ...
end
```

which will assign `[]` to `@inventory` only if it was `nil` or `false` (i.e. the first time you call `inventory`).

A getter that just returns the corresponding instance variable (as in the former example) can also be created via [`attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader):

```
class Player
  attr_reader :inventory

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out 10 seconds after posting this, after messing about with it for an hour.

I needed to add `inventory` to `def initialize`, and then pass an empty array to `player = Player.new(10,1,2,6)` so it became `player = Player.new(10,1,2,6,[])`.

I still don't know why this works.

Comment: Even with this change, your `inventory` method would still "reset" the array.